# How can I make deep learning model training more faster on GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have tried to train VGG16 model using Tensorflow 2.0 for imagenet data on Titan RTX GPU (24G memory ).

But, estimated training time is about 52 days.(Batch size is 128, for 300 epochs)

Is it normal situation? I think it is so strange.

And, could I know there is some way to accelerate training my model?

This [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jyh2378/4a8f10a6eaf00ac7883fbf9c0e05d9dd/untitled0.ipynb) is my all code. Thank you.

Comment: We need more information to help diagnose the issue. Can you post your code somewhere?

Comment: @Marijn van Vliet Please see [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CDgDZ-rynXaL8wd_RABt5vyA10S1tS5I#scrollTo=QErgBkAklk13). It is my all code except data.